# GitLab Health Check without token

Tags: gitlab

I've got GitLab 10.5.6. I'd like to use Health Check information in my monitoring system. I can configure it by using Health Check endpoints with health check access token, but as this solution is depracated, I want to use IP whitelist. And I have some problems with it.

According to this article https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/ip_whitelist.html I edited `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and added this line (as this GitLab was installed around version 7 or even older I think):

> gitlab_rails['monitoring_whitelist'] = ['127.0.0.0/8', '192.168.0.1', 'X.X.X.X', 'Y.Y.Y.Y']

where X.X.X.X is IP of my computer and Y.Y.Y.Y is IP of server with GitLab. After it I executed reconfiguration (`gitlab-ctl reconfigure`). And started tests... Below logs are from `production.log` file.

Execution of `curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/-/readiness` on server Y.Y.Y.Y returns proper JSON with expected data:

> Started GET "/-/readiness" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-24 20:01:31 +0100
>   Processing by HealthController#readiness as */*
>   Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Execution of `curl http://Y.Y.Y.Y:8888/-/readiness` on server Y.Y.Y.Y returns error:

> Started GET "/-/readiness" for Y.Y.Y.Y at 2018-03-24 21:20:04 +0100
>   Processing by HealthController#readiness as */*
>   Filter chain halted as :validate_ip_whitelisted_or_valid_token! rendered or redirected
>   Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Accessing address http://Y.Y.Y.Y:8888/-/readiness through Firefox browser on computer X.X.X.X returns error:

> Started GET "/-/readiness" for X.X.X.X at 2018-03-24 20:03:04 +0100
>   Processing by HealthController#readiness as HTML
>   Filter chain halted as :validate_ip_whitelisted_or_valid_token! rendered or redirected
>   Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Accessing address http://Y.Y.Y.Y:8888/-/readiness?token=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ through Firefox browser on computer X.X.X.X returns proper JSON with expected data.

I don't have any idea what I can check more. Maybe there's lack of any more configuration in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` as it's quite old GitLab instance.